# Toggling bluetooth on/off

Tags: blackberry

Can an app toggle bluetooth on/off without prompting the user? Can an app read the list of the ids of nearby discoverable devices? If so, which function returns such a list? This is in the context of blackberry devices.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting bluetooth device "ids"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466311/detecting-bluetooth-device-ids)

Comment: Note quite because this is in the context of blackberry devices.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possable (through the API) for a third party application to turn on BlueTooth. The best that you can do is open a BlueTooth connection is a way that will prompt the user to turn it on if it isn't already.

In general, the BlackBerry OS won't let third party applications do things behind the user's back that could compromise data security.